# X-Sendfile ownCloud 404 error

Tags: debian, apache-http-server, raspberry-pi, owncloud

I have a problem with X-Sendfile on Apache on Debian with ownCloud. When I want to download single file I got an error:

> The requested URL /owncloud/index.php/apps/files/ajax/download.php was
>   not found on this server.

My config in `sites-enabled/000-default` (and `000-default-ssl`) is
Webserver root is `/media/usb/www/` and ownCloud data folder is `/media/usb/owncloud/data`

```
<Directory /media/usb/www/owncloud>
    Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
    SetEnv MOD_X_SENDFILE_ENABLED 1
    XSendFile On
    XSendFilePath /tmp/oc-noclean
    XSendFilePath /media/usb/owncloud/data
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 1):

Even though five months passed…

Your config seems to be ok. Here is mine, which is working (after modifying the XSendFilePath):

```
<Directory /home/usr/public_html/oc>
  AllowOverride All
  Satisfy Any

  <IfModule mod_xsendfile.c>
    SetEnv MOD_X_SENDFILE_ENABLED 1
    XSendFile On
    XSendFilePath /home/usr/data/owncloud
  </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

ownCloud runs from `/home/usr/public_html/oc` and the corresponding data is in `/home/usr/data/owncloud`

Do not forget to restart Apache

```
service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as an update: XSendfile support was removed with ownCloud 8.2.0 - see https://github.com/owncloud/core/issues/18870 for more details. This is needed to be done because otherwise proper locking isn't possible.